# Using Jsoup to find elements troubles

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, nodes

I don't really know much about HTML parsers(using Jsoup currently) and have tried many times and can not get it to work due to my poor understanding of it, so please bare that in mind.

Anyway I am trying to grab certain parts of an HTML document. This is what I want to be extracted:

```
<div class ="detNane" >
<a class="detLink" title="Details for Hock part3">Hock part3</a></div>
```

Obviously the HTML document has multiple [div class="detName"] and I want to extract all text in each detName div class. I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector for this:

```
Document doc = // parse your document here or connect to a website


for( Element element : doc.select("div.detNane") )
{
    System.out.println(element.text()); // Print the text of that element
}
```